# explode() give me Undefined offset in php

Tags: php, explode

What is wrong with my funky code?
I post using ajax a string
fore ex:`309534368.gif,400559388.jpg,859954067.jpg,821646469.jpg`
In my php scrip I write this

```
$gr = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9-,.]#i', '', $_POST['gr']);
  $array_gr = explode(',',$gr);
  if(count($array_gr)>=1){
      for($i=0;$i<= count($array_gr);$i++){
       $corentimg=$array_gr[$i];
......
```

and when I run my code I get what I want + `Notice Undefined offset`:
on this line  `$corentimg=$array_gr[$i];`

Why?

Comment: 4 items starting from `0` the max index is `3` but `count()` returns 4.

Comment: `$i < count($array_gr)`

Comment: My ajax string could be N long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is if condition error with your code Replace `<=` with `<`.

```
    for($i=0; $i< count($array_gr);$i++){
         $corentimg=$array_gr[$i];
............
```

Comment: Welcome @TomerTouitou, Please accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

While Tiger and Razib's answer is totally correct, I wanted to submit an answer that actually explains why you're getting the error anyways.

Firstly, changing your <= to < does fix the issue, but why?

---

**Take this array as an example**

Here we define an array that contains some words:

```
$array = ["cake","apple","tree","log"];
```

The above array has 4 "elements" inside of it: cake, apple, tree and log.

Printing the array via a var_dump (or whatever else) will reveal the following:

```
0: cake
1: apple
2: tree
3: log
```

---

**The "Problem"**

Using count($array) will return 4, which is correct as there are 4 elements inside the array, however because PHP's indexes start at zero, 4 is actually wrong.

The correct size would be count($array)-1 (= 3)

As your forloop loops around each element of the array, it hits:

```
$item = $array[4]
```

Which is element position five (as we start at zero), this position does not exist, thus you get the 'Undefined offset' error

---

**The Fix**

The fix given to change your code from <= (Less than or Equal too) to just < (Less than) fixes the issue, as the forloop will loop from zero, to less than 4 (thus 3, which explained above is the correct size of the array in PHP term)

I hope this helps you understand, and anyone else that finds this post on Google later why using < (or instead just count($array)-1) is the option needed for PHP Arrays

Comment: Mark Phillips thanks for your explains ! it would help other I just didn't notice I use <= but you are also great man  !

Answer (score 0):

in `for` loop should be `$i < count($array_gr)` not `$i <= count($array_gr)` like bellow :

```
<?php
$gr = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9-,.]#i', '', $_POST['gr']);
$array_gr = explode(',',$gr);
if(count($array_gr)>=1){
  for($i=0;$i<count($array_gr);$i++){
    $corentimg=$array_gr[$i];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Razib Al Mamun  thanks for your help !! Tiger already answer me